# how to create partition on monthly basis in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to upload data into bigquery partitioned table using dataflow .I have successfully uploaded data on date basis and fetched this data on monthly basis using bigquery but my moto is to upload data on monthly basis/yearly basis. Is there any way to do that using dataflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have "monthly" partitions by using the date for the start of each month. For August, for example, you would store everything in the `yourtable$20170801` partition. You would need to have some application-side logic to determine the appropriate `$YYYYmmdd` suffix for the table into which you are writing using Dataflow.